# error in installing artemis in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I want to install artemis with

```
sudo apt-get install artemis
```

But I encounter the following error:

> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I've upgraded and upgraded the packages, but I got back to error again. Which output is as follows:

```
 Get:1330 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic/universe
 libmeanwhile1 amd64 1.0.2-9 [72.6 kB]
 Get:1331 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic/universe
 telepathy-gabble amd64 0.18.4-1 [570 kB]
 ..    
 Get:1578 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic/main
 usb-modeswitch-data all 20170806-2 [30.7 kB]
 Fetched 630 MB in 3h 7min 9s (56.1 kB/s)
 Extracting templates from packages: 100%
 Preconfiguring packages ...
 setting xserver-xorg-legacy/xwrapper/allowed_users from configuration file
 dpkg-deb: error: archive
 '/var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb' has
 premature member 'control.tar.xz' before 'control.tar.gz', giving up
dpkg: error processing archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Try to remove problematic archive with `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb` and then retry.

Comment: i did it, but again, I encountered an error

Comment: Please add contents your answer to your question. I don't understand how it is related to original problem. Also please remove mention of 14.04 if you are using 18.04. Try to fix your problems with `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt-get install -f`, `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. FYI: on my clean 18.04 LTS I can simulate  installation of `artemis` without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error I encountered :
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDro1.png)

@N0rbert